# If element has left value of X then stop function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to make an element move in from the left/right on scroll whilst rotating. When they reach a certain value I want the function to stop, I want the element to move small incremements on mouse scroll.

I've added an IF statemenet but it seems to stop my function from working? I also want my elements to be the correct way around when they stop.

I can't think of the best way to do this so below is my attempt, has anybody an idea?

http://jsfiddle.net/25P7K/1/

```
// If 'firstChart' left value is 40 then stop animation on scroll.

$(window).bind('scroll',function(){

    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
    chartContainer = ($('.chartContainer').offset().top - scrollTop),
    deg = -$(window).scrollTop() * 5;

    // If I remove this it works but the animation doesnt stop? 
    if(parseInt($('.firstChart').css('left')) <= 40){ 

        $('.firstChart').css({
            'left': (chartContainer / 1) + "px",
            'transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)'
        });

        $('.secondChart').css({
            'right': (chartContainer / 1) + "px",
            'transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)'
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: What is the value of $('.firstChart').css('left').  My guess is it's undefined and therefore causing your script to fail.

Comment: You have a syntax error on the `if` statement. This will be stopping it from firing.

Comment: Even when fixing the condition it wont work as the left value is more than 40 as soon as you touch the scroll, so nothing ever happens -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/25P7K/3/

Answer (score 0):

You have an incorrect end to your `if` statement, using `});` instead of `}`.

```
$(window).bind('scroll',function(){
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
    chartContainer = ($('.chartContainer').offset().top - scrollTop),
    deg = -$(window).scrollTop() * 5;

    var firstChartLeft = parseInt($('.firstChart').css('left'));
    //alert(firstChartLeft); /* uncomment for testing */
    if(firstChartLeft <= 40 || firstChartLeft==null){         
        $('.firstChart').css({
            'left': (chartContainer / 1) + "px",
            'transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)'
        });        
        $('.secondChart').css({
            'right': (chartContainer / 1) + "px",
            'transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)'
        });        
    }    
});
```